# How to correctly pass values to wpdb->prepare()?

Tags: wp-query, query, sql, wpdb

Look here:

```
// $term_slugs is a function argument: array('foto', 'video')

$term_query = "t.slug IN ('" . implode("','",$term_slugs) . "') ";

$ids = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
  SELECT
    m.meta_value
  FROM
    " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts p
    INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta m ON m.post_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships rel ON p.ID = rel.object_id
    INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "terms t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
  WHERE
    p.post_type = '%s'
    AND m.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND %s
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 1
",
$post_type, $term_query
));
```

This will write something like:

```
WHERE
  p.post_type = 'gallery'
  AND m.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
  AND 't.slug IN (\'foto\',\'video\') '
```

Shuold be:

```
WHERE
  p.post_type = 'gallery'
  AND m.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
  AND t.slug IN ('foto','video')
```

How to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an answer by myself..

(sample code)

```
$args_array = array($post_type);
$term_slugs = array('foto', 'video');

// create a string like '%s, %s' ecc
$placeholders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($term_slugs), "%s"));
$term_query = "t.slug IN ($placeholders) ";
$args_array = array_merge($args_array, $term_slugs);

$ids = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
  SELECT
    m.meta_value
  FROM
    " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts p
    INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta m ON m.post_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships rel ON p.ID = rel.object_id
    INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "terms t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
  WHERE
    p.post_type = '%s'
    AND m.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $term_query
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 1
",
$args_array // pass substitutions as an array
));
```